# sql update data in 2nd db from 1st db only where table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I'm trying to move some tables from a live db to another db, which will then be made live after the data has been transferred. The 2nd db exists on a server with 2008, and the migration is from 2012. which has caused a few problems

Originally I did a full DB export with Scripts. because the export tool wouldnt go to previous versions. - after the full export I deleted the superfluous tables on db2. as I am only moving 40 or so out of about 200.

Now the DB structure is set up, all is working. with out of date-data. and everything is ready to be switched once the data is made up to date. So i'd ideally like a script that checks to see if a table in db1 exists in db2, then if it does to copy across all rows. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use a `powershell` script to connect it to secondary db, get the list of tables and then do a `bcp out ` of those tables from live db and then `bcp in` in the secondary db. a simple sql script will not be able to connect to both instances unless you want to go through using linked server route

Answer (score 2):

If creating a linked server is not an option then you can try using sql server import data wizard to transfer data from one db to another. 
Use the following link for how-to:
[Import data easily in sql server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a procedure on DB2 that returns a result based on the table you're checking:

```
USE [DB2]

CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.CHECKDB2TABLE

@TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)

AS

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE (TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME)
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'TRUE'
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'FALSE'
    END
```

Then use the procedure to check DB2 and create a conditional statement based on that output to copy across the table.

```
EXEC DB2.dbo.CheckDB2Table @TABLENAME='Tablename'
```

Thanks.

Comment: the data migration is between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012. OP will not be able to call the procedure directly.

Comment: So the databases are on separate servers? In that case you can create a linked server and configure RPC. Then call it remotely... Same idea and result.