# SELECT data from 1st table whether exists or not in 2nd table but with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need some help from some `sql/postgres` guru's. What I'm trying to accomplish is I have a table for `tracks`, `genres` and `playlists`. I need to select from table `tracks` if it already exists in `track_playlists` or not exists. Which I have kind of done already. Here is current code.

```
SELECT tr.*, MAX(tp.played) as last FROM tracks as tr 
LEFT JOIN track_genres as tg ON tr.trk_id = tg.trk_id 
LEFT JOIN track_playlists as tp ON tr.trk_id = tp.trk_id 
AND tp.mem_id=12345 AND tp.chn_id=9 
AND tp.played > EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '4 hours') 
AND (tr.artist != tp.artist AND tp.played > EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hours'))
WHERE tg.rotation=2 GROUP BY tr.trk_id ORDER BY last ASC LIMIT 6
```

Example scenario:

Table `tracks`

```
trk_id | artist  | title
-------------------------
1      | artist1 | title1
2      | artist1 | title2
3      | artist2 | title1
4      | artist3 | title1
5      | artist4 | title1
6      | artist5 | title1
7      | artist1 | title3
8      | artist6 | title1
```

Table `track_genres`

```
gen_id | trk_id | rotation
--------------------------
1      | 1       | 9 
2      | 2       | 9
3      | 3       | 2
4      | 4       | 3
5      | 5       | 9
6      | 6       | 2
7      | 7       | 10
8      | 8       | 9
```

Table `track_playlists`

```
pla_id | mem_id  | trk_id | chn_id | artist  | title | played
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here are the tables that I am dealing with. Currently when a user starts out the `track_playlist` for them is empty. When they select a genre it should populate this table but not all at once hence the `Limit` clause, and it needs to select songs based on whether there are songs already or not in this table for the user. If there aren't any songs then it selects the songs via select query I'm trying. As the songs play, when it goes to pull new songs it needs to see what songs are already there in `track_playlist`. If the song is already in the playlist table then it should skip it and only pull songs that are not in the playlist table yet for this user. Once `all` songs are finally in the playlist for the user, it just needs to check the `played` `timestamp` to see if the last time played for that song is greater than 4 hours and that it's the oldest track by `timestamp` (least recently played) and not an artist that has played in last 1 hour.

I hope this is a bit more clear.

I used this answer to help me with the query of empty or not.

[sql update data in 2nd db from 1st db only where table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670680/sql-update-data-in-2nd-db-from-1st-db-only-where-table-exists)

Comment: Please give us some sample data with your expected result for more clarification ;).

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to decipher which is probably why no-one has taken a crack at it yet. It would be easier if you provided sample tables and data and results, or even an sqlfiddle.  `---` For now I would say that _and is the least recently played track_ is unclear and not reflected in your query, and that `AND (tr.artist != tp.artist AND tp.played > EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hours'))` doesn't look right - You already join `tr` to `tp` on `trk_id`, but then say the artist must be different? I think perhaps you are combining too many things into a single join.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need two sub-queries:
Last played time per artist:

```
select artist, max(played) 
from track_playlists 
WHERE mem_id=12345 AND chn_id=9 
GROUP BY artist
```

Last Played time per track:

```
select trk_id, max(played) 
from track_playlists 
WHERE mem_id=12345 AND chn_id=9 
GROUP BY trk_id
```

Then join your track and genre tables to them applying the conditions (you will need to use LEFT JOIN to ensure that new track and artists are always included). You will also need an extra check for the last played artist using the EXISTS, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT tr.*, tl.track_last_played, al.artist_last_played,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tr.artist) rn
FROM tracks as tr 
LEFT JOIN track_genres as tg ON tr.trk_id = tg.trk_id 
LEFT JOIN (select artist, max(played) as artist_last_played 
           from track_playlists 
           WHERE mem_id=12345 AND chn_id=9
           GROUP BY artist) as al 
   ON tr.artist = al.artist
LEFT JOIN (select trk_id, max(played) as track_last_played 
           from track_playlists 
           WHERE mem_id=12345 AND chn_id=9
           GROUP BY trk_id) as tl 
   ON tr.trk_id = tl.trk_id 
WHERE (tl.track_last_played IS NULL OR tl.track_last_played < EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '4 hours') )
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM track_playlists WHERE mem_id=12345 AND chn_id=9 
                AND artist = tr.artist                
                AND played > EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hours'))
) a
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY track_last_played, artist_last_played ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60268/8)

Comment: Thanks for trying this. I don't see a clause for the mem_id. It's user specific. `AND tp.mem_id=12345 AND tp.chn_id=9` where exactly would that go?

Comment: So, the tracks need to be in the `track_playlists` in order to be played?

Comment: Yes correct. I was updating the question for clarity when you answered. Have a look at edit below the tables example.

Comment: I did some testing and it didnt quite work correctly as I anticipated. I changed the limit to 1 and then put that query in a foreach loop, and it gave me `artist1, artist1, artist1, artist4, artist6, artist4`, You can see it repeated 2 artists. Since Artist1 had already been entered in the table, it shouldn't have selected that one on the next iteration. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was thinking it might need some type of Not exists clause, but sure if that would work.

Comment: Sure, there is a bug. The conditions for tl.track_last_played  and al.artist_last_played should be `<` not `>`. I have fixed the answer

Comment: That will probably fix it when there is data for `played`, but remember when it first checks the table it's not there yet. So played is empty because these songs haven't been played yet. So I'm trying to do 6 inserts with foreach loop (there's a reason) and it's still doing `artist1/title1, artist1/title1, artist1/title1, artist4/title1, artist6/title1, artist4/title1`. It puts the same song in the DB 3 times.  I think we are close though. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: Try it now. I have also added the SQL Fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I used the fiddle and removed the data from the playlist so that it's empty as it would be for a user. And now you can see what I mean. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1c3db/2). It's pulling same artist twice. It should not allow for both results to be the same artist because then it would play back to back. That is what the hour interval would be for but `played` has no value yet. That's the tough part.

Comment: Got it. Check the updated answer. I have used the ROW_NUMBER() to restrict each artist appear once per the result set